# Confidence intervals (ex-ante) for not-least squere forecasting method

Tags: confidence-interval, forecasting, least-squares, prediction-interval

Assume that we know the model of physical experience (for example - the pendulum is moving forward - then the position $s = vt + b\sin(t)$, where $t$ is time and $v$ and $b$ do not matter).

We have measured some points. We can predict (forecast) next points, but how to measure the confidence interval of predicted ones (ex-ante)? We can not use the least squares method because of the sine part. I can find the method for least squares, but not for the other method of function approximations.

Comment: I think you mean "prediction interval". If v and b are known, then all you need to find is the residual variance. If v and b are unknown, you can use ordinary least squares as the equation is linear in the coefficients.

Comment: To continue @Rob's thought: you probably need to estimate a rate coefficient in this model, such as $vt + b\sin(\omega t)$. That would make it truly non-linear. But the immediate concern is that **this question needs to explain what data are available in order to be answerable.**

Comment: Assume that I have time series of measured values from 'black box'. It looks like a sine wave rising (vt + bsin(t)). I can subtract linear trend form the series (have the vt factor) and then using FFT can obtain the b*sin(t+x) factor. Having both factors I can predict the next positions (for the future) but I need to measure the confidence intervals of such predictions. I assume that confidence intervals would depend on the size of the time series set, and on the approximation erros. All I found is the least square method for measuring 'ex-ante' confidence intervals.